# MS Office 365 Exchange calendar API using JAVA

Tags: ms-office, office365, exchangewebservices

Here are the things which I'm looking to do with Office 365 Exchange calendar:

1. creating/updating/deleting events in exchange calendar for bulk for users
2. creating resource/secondary calendars and subscribing users to those calendars.
3. creating groups of users
4. control over the content of the event detail in calendar as to who can
   see what and hiding attendees list to users.
5. master or admin admin account which has control over all the users calendars

It would be great if I could get the answers or guidance. I'm sure it will not be as is implementation as there would be workarounds available.
we have done all the above with GOOGLE calendar JAVA API and now want to achieve it in office 365.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you are asking for a Java toolkit which is off-topic here. If you are looking for software you can ask at [softwarerecs.se], *but make sure you write a good question*: your mention of Google calendar is irrelevant to the question, you are not telling if you are going to use the SOAP or the REST interface of the EWS API. At [softwarerecs.se] you also cannot ask "How do I..."

Comment: And have you looked at the [ews-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) library?